# Does wave function always mean position in time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Does wave function always mean position in time? If we take an entangled state wave function $\frac1{\sqrt2} (|0>|0>+|1>|1>)$, we see nothing about position and time.

Comment: No, it can depend on any quantum number or state

Answer (score 1):

Strictly the wave function is a function of position at given time, but it also has arguments of other quantum numbers, such as spin. If we are interested in spin and not  position, then it is common just to write the spin components of the wave function and to still refer to it as the wave function. This is typically the case for measurements on entangled states. We also refer to the momentum space wave function when the state is given in terms of momentum rather than position.

Answer (score 0):

A wavefunction $\psi(x,t)$ is the coefficient of a normalised vector in Hilbert space $\big(|\psi(t)\rangle\big)$ when expressed in the position basis $\big(|x\rangle\big)$. In other words,
$$|\psi(t)\rangle=\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|\psi(t)\rangle=\int dx|x \rangle\psi(x,t)$$

In your case, what you have is a vector in Hilbert space. If you project it onto space you’ll get the wavefunction.